# Page_unload to reset textbox

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible that Page_Unload event can reset textbox.text? I found that can't!

Markup

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Do something1" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Do something2" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="Do something3" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind

```
Protected Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
    Method1()
End Sub

Protected Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    Method2()
End Sub

Protected Sub btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
    Method3()
End Sub

Private Sub Method1()
    'Do something
End Sub

Private Sub Method2()
    'Do something
End Sub

Private Sub Method3()
    'Do something
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Unload(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
    txt.Text = String.Empty
End Sub
```

You may think that putting the `txt.Text = String.Empty` in every method is the best way to solve this problem, but how about if I have 80 buttons, then I have to put the `txt.Text = String.Empty` in 80 button click event. Does there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [asp.net page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

The event that is called after all button clicks is PreRender.

You can override the OnPreRender to clear such text.

[image: Page life cycle]